# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected “;” in react JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, popup

I am new to ReactJS. This is my first React Program. I have tried with some tutorials but it shows some errors. I want to open popup windows in React I used below code to open popup windows but I am getting an error. Kindly fix the issue. My code is given below:

```
<html>
          <body>
            <div>
              <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
                  var w = window.open("", "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
                  $w.html("<textarea></textarea>");
              });  // getting error here.
            });  // getting error here.

            </script>
            </div>
          <a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
          <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
            <p>test</p>
          </div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Error is

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

                     //var $w = $(w.document.body);     
                     $w.html("<textarea></textarea>");  
               });
                 ^
               });
               </script>
            <a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong understanding of how react works, since you are using plain html to build what you are showing here. First google "create react app", react uses JSX which is like combination of JS and Html, so you don't need to have script tags or html tags inside of your code, and you do not code inside of html file, you should be coding inside file that ends with js or jsx and you create as many of them as you want. It's best to have file for each bigger component, so your code is like pieces of legos and website is what you built with these legos.